# How to turn off logging in optaplanner?

Tags: optaplanner

I just want to turn off the logging. I found this in the documentation:
https://docs.jboss.org/optaplanner/release/6.2.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#logging

However, my project doesnt have a logback.xml file.

Any suggestions?

**Edit:**

I've now added the following logback.xml file to the root directory of my classpath:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="false">

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type
         ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="warn">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

These jar files are inside my classpath:

- antlr-runtime-3.5.jar
- commons-codec-1.4.jar
- commons-io-2.1.jar
- commons-lang-2.6.jar
- commons-math3-3.2.jar
- dom4j-1.6.1.jar
- drools-compiler-6.2.0.Final.jar
- drools-core-6.2.0.Final.jar
- drools-decisiontables-6.2.0.Final.jar
- drools-templates-6.2.0.Final.jar
- ecj-4.3.1.jar
- freemarker-2.3.19.jar
- guava-13.0.1.jar
- jacop-4.2.0.jar
- jcommon-1.0.23.jar
- jfreechart-1.0.19.jar
- jgrapht-core-0.9.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
- kie-api-6.2.0.Final.jar
- kie-internal-6.2.0.Final.jar
- logback-classic-1.0.9.jar
- logback-core-1.0.9.jar
- mvel2-2.2.4.Final.jar
- optaplanner-benchmark-6.2.0.Final.jar
- optaplanner-core-6.2.0.Final.jar
- poi-3.10.1.jar
- poi-ooxml-3.10.1.jar
- poi-ooxml-schemas-3.10.1.jar
- protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar
- slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar
- stax-api-1.0.1.jar
- xml-apis-1.3.04.jar
- xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar
- xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar
- xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar
- xstream-1.4.7.jar

These are the logging messages:

```
12:33:09.729 [main] DEBUG o.o.c.i.l.DefaultLocalSearchPhase -     LS step (47), time spent (4230), score (-452), new best score (-452), accepted/selected move count (1000/1043), picked move (gc.Vertex@36bc2602 => 170).
12:33:09.808 [main] DEBUG o.o.c.i.l.DefaultLocalSearchPhase -     LS step (48), time spent (4309), score (-447), new best score (-447), accepted/selected move count (1000/1035), picked move (gc.Vertex@265753b0 => 169).
12:33:09.887 [main] DEBUG o.o.c.i.l.DefaultLocalSearchPhase -     LS step (49), time spent (4388), score (-442), new best score (-442), accepted/selected move count (1000/1042), picked move (gc.Vertex@70dc77a8 => 169).
12:33:09.968 [main] DEBUG o.o.c.i.l.DefaultLocalSearchPhase -     LS step (50), time spent (4469), score (-437), new best score (-437), accepted/selected move count (1000/1052), picked move (gc.Vertex@47f128ad => 106).
12:33:10.048 [main] DEBUG o.o.c.i.l.DefaultLocalSearchPhase -     LS step (51), time spent (4549), score (-432), new best score (-432), accepted/selected move count (1000/1045), picked move (gc.Vertex@2abbb9f2 => 229).
12:33:10.127 [main] DEBUG o.o.c.i.l.DefaultLocalSearchPhase -     LS step (52), time spent (4628), score (-427), new best score (-427), accepted/selected move count (1000/1034), picked move (gc.Vertex@2db68692 => 234).
12:33:10.208 [main] DEBUG o.o.c.i.l.DefaultLocalSearchPhase -     LS step (53), time spent (4709), score (-422), new best score (-422), accepted/selected move count (1000/1054), picked move (gc.Vertex@fa3582a => 129).
12:33:10.286 [main] DEBUG o.o.c.i.l.DefaultLocalSearchPhase -     LS step (54), time spent (4787), score (-417), new best score (-417), accepted/selected move count (1000/1046), picked move (gc.Vertex@56f3b98c => 137).
12:33:10.365 [main] DEBUG o.o.c.i.l.DefaultLocalSearchPhase -     LS step (55), time spent (4866), score (-412), new best score (-412), accepted/selected move count (1000/1044), picked move (gc.Vertex@7e25a483 => 170).
12:33:10.441 [main] DEBUG o.o.c.i.l.DefaultLocalSearchPhase -     LS step (56), time spent (4942), score (-407), new best score (-407), accepted/selected move count (1000/1042), picked move (gc.Vertex@330d8014 => 127).
12:33:10.519 [main] DEBUG o.o.c.i.l.DefaultLocalSearchPhase -     LS step (57), time spent (5020), score (-402), new best score (-402), accepted/selected move count (1000/1048), picked move (gc.Vertex@c911382 => 195).
12:33:10.598 [main] DEBUG o.o.c.i.l.DefaultLocalSearchPhase -     LS step (58), time spent (5099), score (-397), new best score (-397), accepted/selected move count (1000/1036), picked move (gc.Vertex@7349c1f6 => 189).
12:33:10.677 [main] DEBUG o.o.c.i.l.DefaultLocalSearchPhase -     LS step (59), time spent (5178), score (-392), new best score (-392), accepted/selected move count (1000/1055), picked move (gc.Vertex@2aab8eb6 => 234).
12:33:10.755 [main] DEBUG o.o.c.i.l.DefaultLocalSearchPhase -     LS step (60), time spent (5256), score (-389), new best score (-389), accepted/selected move count (1000/1049), picked move (gc.Vertex@7d19367b => 137).
```

Comment: It's strange that you have logging without actually doing something for it. Check if you have a dependency to optaplanner-examples. You shouldn't have that (only optaplanner-core and optaplanner-benchmark)

Answer (score 2):

I've now solved the problem by adding the following two lines to my code:

```
LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
loggerContext.stop();
```

Comment: That's a dirty hack :) I wonder which of the jars in your classpath is configuring logback: one of them must have that logback.xml file (if it's not your project itself in src/main/resources)

Answer (score 1):

Look in your classpath to see what logging implementation you use. Depending on what you find there:

- logback-classic.jar: add a logback.xml and set everything to log level WARN
- log4j.jar: add a log4j.xml (or properties) and set everything to log level WARN

If you just see slf4j-api, then you'll probably want to add a slf4j-noop or something. If you see slf4j-over-X, then you'll want to configure X to only log level WARN.

Comment: In my classpath are slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar, logback-classic-1.0.9.jar, logback-core-1.0.9.jar. If I remove one of them, I get an exception. Where should I put the logback.xml?

Comment: in the root of the classpath. Check that optaplanner-examples.jar is not in your classpath, as it also has a logback.xml in the root of the classpath.